# How does viewset aligns with rest methods

Tags: django, api, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am relatively new to DRF, but found viewsets an amazing abstraction technique for writing RESTful API. I am having a hard time correlating Viewsets with REST methods though. Let's say I have a viewset for Userprofiles and somebody new creates a profile on client.

1. Should this send a PUT or a POST ?
2. Which url should this request go to, http://user or http://user/new_id ?
3. If I want this profile only accessible to the user or admin(all CRUD operations), then where should I handle the code for making it inaccessible to others ?
4. Should I create a new permission ? If yes, should I handle rest methods in has_permission/has_object_permission ?

I have gone through the tutorial, and know how permissions/mixins works, but I am not able to connect these dots here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ In general, `POST` is for creating new, `PUT` is for updating. See the docs on the [SimpleRouter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter) to show how the various types of Http methods align with various actions in your Django backend.

2/ You'll find that different situations call for different routing methods. If yours is standard, you may want to use a SimpleRouter like the example above. In that case, creating a new user would be a `POST` request to `/user/` and updating a user would be a `PUT` request to `/user/{{user_id}}/`.

3/ To limit access to various API methods, you want to use Permissions. It's possible that you could use one of DRF's [Custom Permissions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions). I've found that in general, if you want only the user to access his/her own profile, it's easier to either use conditional logic within a view (i.e., return a DRF [PermissionDenied exception](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#permissiondenied) in the view logic if the `request.user.pk` is not the pk of that REST url. More often than not, I've used the `UserPassesTestMixin` from [Django Braces](https://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/latest/access.html#userpassestestmixin), that works pretty well to filter user permissions.

4/ I guess the Django Braces mixin above answers this question. You should include a `test_func` method if you're using Django Braces that returns `True` if you want to grant the user access, and `False` otherwise.

Hope this helps! I agree that these are difficult parts of DRF and perhaps some of these could more effectively get incorporated into the source. Good luck!